# Cannot write bytes: Broken

Tags: boot, pipe

I am getting an error at beginning while booting itself and so i can't get to my desktop.

When i boot i select Ubuntu and then after disabled bios messages i run directly into the black screen with broken pipe error.

In my previous session i had physically removed OpenCV folder which had all it's libraries and avr32 toolchain which was not associated and was unused. plus i had done:
 `sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update`

and then i shut down. Next morning i have this broken pipe error!

Now, i have no idea what i should do.

Thank god i have win7 on dual boot so at least i can get help from forum.

Please reply